# go: fcgi не принимает запрос

Tags: golang, fastcgi

изучаю вот этот мануал https://lectureswww.readthedocs.io/5.web.server/self.html
соответственно , копирую

```html
package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "net"
 "net/http"
 "net/http/fcgi"
)

func handler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
 fmt.Fprint(res, "Hello World!")
}

func main() {
 // For local machine
 // l, _ := net.Listen("unix", "/var/run/go-fcgi.sock")

 l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:5000") // TCP 5000 listen
 if err != nil {
  return
 }
 http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
 fcgi.Serve(l, nil)
}
```

открываю в браузере  localhost:5000 и получаю  connection reset.  в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы недочитали:

> Настройка Nginx
>
> ```
> # fcgi.nginx
> location /fastcgi_hello {
>     # host and port to fastcgi server
>     include         fastcgi.conf;
>     fastcgi_pass 172.17.0.89:5000;
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> Client Request ----> Nginx (Reverse-Proxy) ----> App. FastCGI Server I. 127.0.0.1:5000
> ```

Для протокола FastCGI нужен сервер приложений, в данном случае Nginx. Если вы хотите без него, то используйте пакет `net/http`.

Comment: поставил nginx, прописал в конфиг указанную строчку, nginx -s reload сделал. добавил fmt.Println("start handle"), запустил, перешел на localhost/fastcgi_hello и получил 504. к тому же, println не сработал. в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @СкерисЯгут А вы правильный IP-адрес указали? Если запускаете на локалке, то надо `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: ох, благодарю, какой же я тупой